# Why are the rationals fixed by this monomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, extension-field, group-homomorphism

The author is defining a $ℚ$-monomorphism $i:ℚ(a)→ℂ$, where $a$ is the real cube root of $2$.

Every element of $ℚ(a)$ is of the form $p+qa+ra^2$, where $p, q, r ∈ℚ$, and 
$$i(p+qa+ra^2)=p+qwa+rw^2a^2$$ where $w=exp(2πi/3)$

---

Why is it that such automorphism will fix the rational numbers?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: If $p+qa+ra^2$ is fixed then $0=(w-1)(qa+ra^2(w+1))$. It follows that $w=-qa/ra^2-1$ is real. Or $r=0$. But in that case $q=0$.

Comment: Take $q=r=0$ in the definition of the map $i$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows directly from the definition of the map $i$ that $i(p)=p$ for all $p \in \mathbb Q$: just take $q=r=0$.

The more interesting question is why the map $i$ is well defined, or equivalently, why every element of $\mathbb Q(a)$ has a *unique* expression of the form $p+qa+ra^2$ with $p,q,r \in \mathbb Q$.